# puzzling DNS behaviour (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, networking, dns, ping, amazon-ec2

(All IPs and names have been censored, hopefully)

This morning we had some connectivity problems in one of our servers. It turns out that changing our connection configuration to be IP-based (not preferable) solves this, but surprisingly DNS did not completely fail.

What happens is that the DNS **sometimes** (within a range of seconds) manages to translate the given url to the corresponding IP and sometimes doesn't (`unknown host`).

What could be causing such behavior? What steps can I take to make sure this is handled well? Other

> badumtsss@02-02-02-02:~$ ping dingding.badumtsss.com
>
> ping: unknown host dingding.badumtsss.com
>
> badumtsss@02-02-02-02:~$ ping dingding.badumtsss.com PING
>   dingding.badumtsss.com (01.01.01.01) 56(84) bytes of data.
>
> 64 bytes from ec2-01-01-01-01.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
>   (01.01.01.01): icmp_req=1 ttl=43 time=18.7 ms 64 bytes from
>   ec2-01-01-01-01.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com (01.01.01.01):
>   icmp_req=2 ttl=43 time=18.5 ms
>   --- dingding.badumtsss.com ping statistics --- 8 packets transmitted, 8 received, 0% packet loss, time 7010ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev =
>   18.523/18.721/18.815/0.147 ms
>
> badumtsss@02-02-02-02:~$ ping dingding.badumtsss.com
>
> ping: unknown host dingding.badumtsss.com
>
> badumtsss@02-02-02-02:~$ ping dingding.badumtsss.com PING
>   dingding.badumtsss.com (01.01.01.01) 56(84) bytes of data. 64 bytes
>   from ec2-01-01-01-01.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com (01.01.01.01):
>   icmp_req=1 ttl=43 time=18.5 ms 64 bytes from
>   ec2-01-01-01-01.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com (01.01.01.01):
>   icmp_req=2 ttl=43 time=18.7 ms ^C
>
> --- dingding.badumtsss.com ping statistics --- 2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev =
>   18.586/18.681/18.777/0.166 ms badumtsss@02-02-02-02:~$ ping dingding.badumtsss.com PING dingding.badumtsss.com (01.01.01.01)
>   56(84) bytes of data. 64 bytes from
>   ec2-01-01-01-01.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com (01.01.01.01):
>   icmp_req=1 ttl=43 time=18.6 ms 64 bytes from
>   ec2-01-01-01-01.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com (01.01.01.01):
>   icmp_req=2 ttl=43 time=18.6 ms ^C
>
> --- dingding.badumtsss.com ping statistics --- 2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev =
>   18.612/18.616/18.621/0.136 ms badumtsss@02-02-02-02:~$ ping dingding.badumtsss.com ping: unknown host dingding.badumtsss.com

Comment: Any connectivity problem, whether client-side or server side.

Comment: IPs work flawlessly so far

Comment: Then the problem is in the connection to your DNSs. Have you tried changing them?

Comment: Not yet, but the same DNS servers work on other servers.

I'll try and do that, but ubuntu changed it's old DNS-changing procedure.

I thought this may be a common problem that I don't know of.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the list of DNS servers in `/etc/resolv.conf` and try to perform the queries directly using e.g. `dig` and see whether you get the correct answer and how long it takes. You can use `tcpdump -vv` or a tool like Wireshark to see what queries are used by the applications.

```
dig some-domain A @name-server
```

Theoretically you could improve the situation by using a local caching nameserver (e.g. `unbound`, `dnsmasq` or even `bind`), but that cover the real problem at best.

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps using ec2 for these queries, using the AWS resolver. If so, open a support case and have them look at the resolver/host combination.